# php_value settings in .htaccess

Tags: apache-httpd, php, php7, htaccess

I am in the process of migrating an Apache WordPress site from CentOS7 to AlmaLinux9.

I installed standard LAMP stuff on the AlamLinux9 system, and restored the MySQL and copied over the html directory.

When I hit the site it throws a `500 Internal Server Error`
I've narrowed it down to the `php_value` settings in the `.htaccess` file as the source of the error.

```
php_value post_max_size 32M
php_value upload_max_filesize 32M
php_value max_execution_time 30
php_value memory_limit 256M
php_value error_log "/var/www/html/mysitename.com/php_errors.log"
```

If I comment out any of the above lines it loads fine.

PHP on both is Version 7.4.33

I've verified the `php.ini` files are also identical.
The CentOS system loads fine as is, but the AlamaLinux won't allow it.

What else is causing the PHP to not like the setting here in the `.htaccess` file?

Comment: Your question is very confused. The sample config you've shown us is not commented. Did you check for other .htaccess files? **What do your logs say?**

Answer (score 1):

You are probably running PHP as FastCGI Process Manager (PHP). You can use `php_value` in `.htaccess` only when PHP is running as an Apache module. When using `php-fpm`, you can use [.user.ini](https://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.per-user.php) as an alternative.

Move your settings to `.user.ini` file:

```
post_max_size=32M
upload_max_filesize=32M
max_execution_time=30
memory_limit=256M
error_log="/var/www/html/mysitename.com/php_errors.log"
```